# Swing simple overlay

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm in the process of making a 2D game in which a player roams around a maze. 
[image: screenshot of the GUI]

I want to implement some sort of "darkness", even something as simple as a transparent shape around the player surrounded by black, like this:
[image: mock-up screenshot]

The problem I've found using Swing is that, while this is possible, it means having to redraw everything, which produces an annoying "flickering" effect every time it happens. Is there a way to make some sort of overlay, or just a good way of doing this in general in Swing? I'm not very experienced with GUI/visual stuff right now so I'd like to stick with Swing if possible.

EDIT: This is my method to paint the background, i.e. the floor, walls and exit:

```
    public final void paintBG(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY); // Screen background
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    // Draw the Walls of the maze
    // scalex and y are for scaling images/walls within the maze since I let users specify how big they want the maze
    for (int j = 0; j < this.height; j++, y += scaley) {
        x = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.width; i++, x += scalex) {
            if (!(maze[j][i].northwall.isBroken())) // If the north wall isn't broken
            {
                g.drawImage(walltile, x, y, scalex, scaley / 5, null); // Draw a wall there (image, xpos, ypos, width, height, observer)
            }
            if (!(maze[j][i].eastwall.isBroken())) // etc
            {
                g.drawImage(walltile, x + scalex, y, scalex / 5, scaley, null);
            }
            if (!(maze[j][i].southwall.isBroken())) {
                g.drawImage(walltile, x, y + scaley, scalex, scaley / 5, null);
            }
            if (!(maze[j][i].westwall.isBroken())) {
                g.drawImage(walltile, x, y, scalex / 5, scaley, null);
            }

            if ((j == mazeinfo.getTargetM()) && (i == mazeinfo.getTargetN())) {
                // Draw the exit
                g.drawImage(jeep, x + (scalex / 2), y + (scaley / 2), cx, cy, null);
                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                if (maze[j][i].northwall.isEdge()) {
                    // Paint over the edge creating a 'way out'
                    g.fillRect(x, y, scalex, scaley / 4);
                } else if (maze[j][i].eastwall.isEdge()) {
                    g.fillRect(x + scalex, y, scalex / 4, scaley);
                } else if (maze[j][i].southwall.isEdge()) {
                    g.fillRect(x, y + scaley, scalex, scaley / 4);
                } else if (maze[j][i].westwall.isEdge()) {
                    g.fillRect(x, y, scalex / 4, scaley);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then have "paintPlayer" and "paintEnemy" methods to paint those sprites each time they move. The background only gets painted once, at the start.

Comment: Thank you for the code -- please show your component's actual paint or paintComponent methods as well.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488853/java-mouse-flashlight-effect/15489299#15489299), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309611/how-to-draw-a-transparent-background/15309868#15309868), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709070/how-to-disable-java-awt-graphics-fillrectint-x-int-y-int-width-int-heights/23709320#23709320), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388942/clear-portion-of-graphics-with-underlying-image/18392674#18392674)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibilities:

- You may be drawing directly in a top level window such as a JFrame. If so, don't draw in the paintComonent method of a JPanel so that you use the automatic double buffering availabe.
- You may be reading in an image from within a painting method, and if so, don't. These methods must paint and paint only and must be blindingly fast.
- You may not be using a BufferedImage in your painting method but creating an image de-novo, and if so, don't. Draw the BufferedImage using `Graphics#drawImage(...)`.
- Perhaps your animation code is off. You may be calling `repaint()` from within paint or paintComponent, something that should never be done.
- And the possible guesses can go on and on...

---

Edit

Your code shows that you may be re-paint the maze with every painting iteration -- don't do this. Instead draw the above into a BufferedImage, and draw that image within your paintComponent method. Then change the BufferedImage if the walls structurally change.

Note that the maze's logical structure (the non-visual data that tells which wall is open, which is closed) should be part of your program's data, and not its code.

Answer (score 3):

Here in an example of using a LayerUI from Oracle's Swing UI documentation. Just change the AlphaComposite constant to something darker.

The following is a LayerUI subclass that draws a translucent circle wherever the mouse moves inside a panel.

```
class SpotlightLayerUI extends LayerUI<JPanel> {
  private boolean mActive;
  private int mX, mY;

  @Override
  public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);
    JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
    jlayer.setLayerEventMask(
      AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK |
      AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
    );
  }

  @Override
  public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
    JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
    jlayer.setLayerEventMask(0);
    super.uninstallUI(c);
  }

  @Override
  public void paint (Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    // Paint the view.
    super.paint (g2, c);

    if (mActive) {
      // Create a radial gradient, transparent in the middle.
      java.awt.geom.Point2D center = new java.awt.geom.Point2D.Float(mX, mY);
      float radius = 72;
      float[] dist = {0.0f, 1.0f};
      Color[] colors = {new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), Color.BLACK};
      RadialGradientPaint p =
          new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors);
      g2.setPaint(p);
      g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
          AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .6f));
      g2.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    }

    g2.dispose();
  }

  @Override
  protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer l) {
    if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED) mActive = true;
    if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED) mActive = false;
    l.repaint();
  }

  @Override
  protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer l) {
    Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), e.getPoint(), l);
    mX = p.x;
    mY = p.y;
    l.repaint();
  }
}
```

To keep the spotlight's center updated on your player, create an event for player movement and register the LayerUI to listen for updates. See the `setLayerEventMask()` example in the JLayer link below.

source: [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

Comment: This is used for a semi-translucent overlay, but not for a background image which is what the original poster is actually needing.